# .net web service deployment from iis to azure

Tags: web-services, azure

I am quite new on web services and asp.net too. I created .net web service and deployed it on IIS. My web service takes some data from android and does some manipulation and store it in text files. Because I am working with localhost so there is no issue with storing data in text files. But now I am publishing this web service to azure portal now I am confused where my data will be stored? should I changed the path ? or what I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local file system on azure cloud service may change so your data may be lost. Better to have the blob storage for storing file. https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/an-introduction-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-/

Comment: thank you for telling me! this is what i wanted to ask